# Lineno \internallinenumbers - how to make a line number label within a figure?

Tags: floats, cross-referencing, line-numbering

This concerns the "lineno" package. The `\linelabel` directive works within the ordinary `linenumbers` environment. How to create a line number label within a `internallinenumbers` environment to be able to reference a line number? I need this to be able to refer to a line in the pseudocode in a figure.

Or, alternatively - is there an environment like `figure` in which the ordinary `linenumbers` and `\linelabel` work?

Answer (score 4):

The package **fancyvrb** provides a line numbering facility (on p. 15 of its documentation is an example for labeling a line number for reference).

More powerful for displaying code is the **listings** package, which comes with an extensive documentation. It provides line numbering and labeling; its environments can go into a floating environment.